# Retrieve extension properties on Azure ADB2C via API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am usin Azure ADB2C and with the API Graph GetUser I want also the extension properties I have configured on Azure Portal.

I've read that I should specify the field on the query string, but the field name is different from the one I chose, and it's something like "extension_GUID_fieldName".

The problem is that I can't get that name, i.e. retrieve the assigned GUID for that name; it seems no API lets you do that, and the only trick I've found is to query via PowerShell which is not a solution for me.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find that GUID in your Azure AD B2C `App registrations` blade by searching `b2c-extensions-app` :
[image]

The Application ID is the GUID that you are looking for. But you should remove all `-` characters. For instance, I have a custom attribute created on portal named "id4GTM":
[image]

If you want to query its value by Microsoft Graph API, this is the query example below:
[image]

Comment: Hi, your solution seems good but trying to do as you say does not seem to work

https://radolovich-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/info_radolovich_net/EZO6Bu6BQ75IjBbZ9h5KA14BIW6ulpvb3v8bNVsAqqPipw?e=Od28DH

https://radolovich-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/info_radolovich_net/ESzdNg6-aDJFq-fF0W6Qf28BKAGp_OZYDVkxNB2y5isD0w?e=phMCQf

https://radolovich-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/info_radolovich_net/ER7TNwNgXjVPrpCocKvWaJIBs03oXh9Y_qrjAhJ239WeXw?e=5Mrjp6

Comment: Ok I got it, it works but the fields have to be initialized on create/update or they are not returned in the get

Comment: @Radox, yes,  you are right. The fields have to be initialized first. Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to mark it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : ) If you have any further questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Already did but a reputation of 15 Is needed ti display my vote :(

Comment: Hi @Radox, you can just click the check under vote to accept it,not voting it  thanks !!

Comment: @Radox, I think you have more than 15 reputation now, LOL , Please mark my answer if it is helpful : )